# Colocando minutos na hora de funcionamento

Tags: php, javascript, variáveis, if, else

Tenho o seguinte código, onde determina a hora de funcionamento do Delivery. Segue código:

```
function delivery(){
  var cep1 = document.getElementById("cep1").value;
  var cep2 = document.getElementById("cep2").value;
  var cep = cep1 + "-" + cep2;
  var data = new Date();
  var mes = data.getMonth() + 1; 
  var diaMes = data.getDate();
  var hoje = diaMes + "/" + mes;
  var diaSemana = data.getDay();
  var hora = data.getHours();           // 0-23
  if(feriados.indexOf(hoje) != -1 || diaSemana == 0 || diaSemana == 6){
      $("#data").venobox().trigger('click');
  }else if(hora < 7 || hora > 16){
      $("#hora").venobox().trigger('click');
  }else if(ceps.indexOf(cep) == -1){
      $("#cep").venobox().trigger('click');
  }else{
      if (diaSemana == 1){
          location.assign("http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/segunda/index_segunda.php");
      } else if (diaSemana == 2){
          location.assign("http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/terca/index_terca.php");
      } else if (diaSemana == 3){
          location.assign("http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/quarta/index_quat.php");
      } else if (diaSemana == 4){
          location.assign("http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/quinta/index_quin.php");
      } else if (diaSemana == 5){
          location.assign("http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/sexta/index_sext.php");
      } else {
          $("#hora").venobox().trigger('click');
      };
  };
 }
```

O que eu não sei fazer e preciso e colocar a hora limite de 16h (hoje) para 15:30, ou seja, colocar os minutos que hoje não existe. Sei que o trecho do código é esse:

```
var hora = data.getHours();         // 0-23
  if(feriados.indexOf(hoje) != -1 || diaSemana == 0 || diaSemana == 6){
      $("#data").venobox().trigger('click');
  }else if(hora < 7 || hora > 16){
      $("#hora").venobox().trigger('click');
```

Só não sei como fazer! Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: var minuto = data.getMinutes();   Assim você conseguira manipular os minutos seu código, agora não sei exatamente o que faz o clique do venobox assim que possível eu pesquiso para contribuir com mais.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você pode resolver isso tranquilamente com a biblioteca [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

Exemplo:

```
moment().format('MM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss'); // 09 29 2017, 3:07:08
```

Comment: Agradeço a atenção, mas sou leigo, não entendi como usar esse código no meu!